# Ionic v3 toggle between light and dark theme at runtime (dynamically)

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, themes

In Ionic v3 there is import of the theme in the file `variable.scss`.

```css
@import 'ionic.theme.default';
```

and can be replaced by the dark theme to use the dark theme instead of the default light theme.

```css
@import 'ionic.theme.dark';
```

Works great. But how to toggle between both themes at runtime? And how to know what theme is currently active to style custom components.

I have already searched the internet, including here. But I found nothing helpful. So I think this is not a duplicate. Maybe I missed something. But there should be a way to import the default AND dark theme and enable toggle between at runtime.

I could write my own themes by css "hacking". But I prefer to use the Ionic preset official way.

Comment: @d.b What do you exactly mean? Yes the css should be generated and separeted in default and with an additional root selector class "dark". Stored locally as js variable is the second step. Just a variable with the theme name. "" or "dark" or "light". This is trivial. But I wondering how to import both themes of Ionic separately.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to import the dark theme in a wrapped context (selector)? The import of `ionic.theme.dark` overwrites the default variables of Ionic. Idk who to switch it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood the problem correctly, first add an `id` to the link

```
<link
    id="color-CSS"
    rel="stylesheet"
    href=".path/light.css"
    type="text/css"
  />
```

Then use a JS function to enable toggle, something like

```
<script>
  const mainTheme = "./path/light.css";
  const altTheme = "./path/dark.css";
  const currentCSS = document.querySelector("#color-CSS");
  function toggleTheme() {       
    if (currentCSS.href.includes(mainTheme)) {
      currentCSS.setAttribute("href", altTheme);
    } else {
      currentCSS.setAttribute("href", mainTheme);
    }
  }    
</script>
```

I'm not sure but the dot (`.`) at the beginning of file path maybe important to get over MIME issues.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but you gave me an idea. I do not have separated css-files. Because the import of ionic.theme.dark just overwrites the scss variables. But I could compile my app twice. Once in light and once in dark mode. And extract the the `main.css` file which holds the Ionic stylings. And place both as `main.css` and `main-dark.css` and switch between. But this is not my prefered solution. But thanks for the idea. :) I will ask a official Ionic developer if theme switching is generally possible. If not your solution is an alternative. I will test it...